# Отправка письма с attachment

Tags: php, email

На почту приходит только изображение с непонятным расширением, не открывающееся из почтового ящика. Текст письма и заголовок вообще не приходят. Нормально работает только `Subject`.

Мой скрипт отправки почты:

```
<?

$imya = $_POST['imya'];
$tel = $_POST['tel'];
$foto = $_POST['foto'];
$soobcenie = $_POST['soobcenie'];

$boundary="boundaryrazdelstroki";
$tema="Новый заказ!";

$headers= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers.="Content-type:multipart/mixed; boudary=$boundary\r\n";
$headers.= "From: sicusstvo@mail.ru\r\n";
$header.="Subject: Vasa\r\n";
$header.="To: SERG\r\n";

$soobceniee="--$boundary\r\n";
$soobceniee.="Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";
$soobceniee.="Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable\r\n";
$soobceniee.="<strong>$tel</strong>\r\n";

$soobceniee.="--$boundary\r\n";
$soobceniee.="Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";
$soobceniee.="Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable\r\n";
$soobceniee.="<p>$soobcenie</p>\r\n";

$soobceniee.="--$boundary\r\n";
$soobceniee.="Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name='im.jpg'\r\n"; 
$soobceniee.="Content-Transfer-Encoding:base64\r\n";
$soobceniee.="Content-Disposition:attachment; filename='im.jpg'\r\n";
$file_name="img/im.jpg";
$file=fopen ($file_name,"rb");
$soobceniee.=chunk_split(base64_encode(fread($file,filesize($file_name))));
$soobceniee.="--$boundary--";

if(mail("моя_почта@rambler.ru", "=?utf-8?B?".base64_encode($tema)."?=", $soobceniee,$headers)){
print"Сообщение отправлено $imya<br><a href='http://мой_сайт.com.ua/rascet.php'>Отправить еще письмо</a>";
}
else 
{
print"<span style='color:red'>Сообщение не отпправлено</span>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Отформатируйте код пожалуйста. Нужно его выделить и нажать кнопку {}

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте как то так

```
$imya = $_POST['imya'];
$tel = $_POST['tel'];
$foto = $_POST['foto'];
$soobcenie = $_POST['soobcenie'];

$from = 'sicusstvo@mail.ru';
$subject = 'Новый заказ!';
$to = 'some@email.com';

$boundary=md5(time());

$n = "\n";
$n2 = "\n\n";

$headers .= 'From: '.$from.''.$n;
$headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$from.''.$n;
$headers .= 'Return-Path: '.$from.''.$n;
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0'.$n;
$headers .= 'Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="'.$boundary.'"'.$n2;

$msg = '';
$msg .= 'Content-Type: multipart/alternative'.$n2;
$msg .= '--'.$boundary.$n2;
$msg .= 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1'.$n2;
$msg .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit'.$n2;

$html = '<strong>'.$tel.'</strong>\r\n';
$html .= '<p>'.$soobcenie.'</p>\r\n"';
$msg .= $html.$n2;

/* attachment */
$file_path = "img/im.jpg";
$file_name = 'im.jpg';

$handle = fopen($file_path, 'rb');
$f_contents = fread($handle, filesize($file_path));
fclose($handle);

$f_contents = chunk_split(base64_encode($f_contents));

$msg .= '--'.$boundary.$n2;
$msg .= 'Content-Type: image/jpeg; name="'.$file_name.'"'.$n2;
$msg .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64'.$n2;
$msg .= 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$file_name.'"'.$n2;
$msg .= $f_contents.$n2;

mail($to, $subject, $msg, $headers);
```